# Why can't I use `isCalculating` property to wait for calculation request to finish

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I need to call the `calculate()` method of the `MKDirections` class in a `for` loop but I am making too many requests for a valid distance to be returned. I have tried putting in a `while` loop that keeps looping until the `isCalculating` property is set to false but I am still making too many requests as evidenced by the `error.debugDescription` message that prints out. How can I wait for the current request to finish before submitting another one?

I have tried putting in a `while` loop to delay submitting another request to the `calculate()` method but the code just keeps making too many requests as evidenced by the `error.debugDescription`.

```
// Step through sites one by one
for siteIndex in 0..<countySites.count {
    var selectedSite = countySites[siteIndex]
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedSite.locationCoordinate)

    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

    let distanceAndDirections = MKDirections(request: request)
    if currentCoordinate != nil {

        group.enter()
        busyCalculating = distanceAndDirections.isCalculating
        while busyCalculating == true {
            busyCalculating = distanceAndDirections.isCalculating
        }

        distanceAndDirections.calculate { (response, error) in

            if error == nil {

                let distanceInMetres = response?.routes.first?.distance
                let distanceInMiles = distanceInMetres! / 1610
                let roundedDistanceInMiles = Int(distanceInMiles.rounded())
                let distanceToSite = roundedDistanceInMiles

                selectedSite.distance = distanceToSite
                self.countySites[siteIndex] = selectedSite

            } else {
                print("error is not nil = \(error.debugDescription)")
            }

            group.leave()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see what exactly gets printed by `error.debugDescription`

Comment: ```error is not nil = Optional(Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=3 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Route information is not available at this moment., MKErrorGEOError=-3, MKErrorGEOErrorUserInfo={
}, MKDirectionsErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available})```

Comment: I have looked up this error message and I have read that it is because I am making too many requests for distance calculation.

Comment: Does the while loop execute at all? I'm thinking busy calculating is going to be false since you haven't called calculate yet.

Comment: No the while loop doesn't execute at all after putting a print statement in saying ```print("in while loop")``` but the previous request stills seems to be getting processed as it produces the above error message.

Comment: What about recursive calls? I answered a similar question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649927/there-is-an-array-with-unspecific-number-of-closures-how-to-nest-them/55650261#55650261 Is that what you are looking for? The while loop is not good, and I don't know what you are doing with the DispatchGroup if you don't want to do parrallels calls.

Comment: You're creating brand new `distanceAndDirections` for each site, and check if it's calculating before starting calculations.  You won't get into `while` loop ever with that logic

Comment: The DispatchGroup is there because the calls to the ```calculate()``` method are asynchronous.

Comment: I need to create a new ```MKDirections``` instance because it's initialisation is dependent upon the currently selected ```selectedSite``` array value.

Comment: @sjlearmonth, yeah, but still you're checking `isCalculating` for just created instance and just created instance only. You should check on those that started before instead. New one is never `isCalculating`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will look at that tomorrow.

Comment: A "busy loop" is a terrible solution. You will peg the thread to 100% CPU with that `while` loop.

Comment: What do you suggest @rmaddy.

Comment: Actually the 'busy loop' never actually enters but the error message is still being produced meaning it is busy

Answer (score 0):

Using a `while` loop that will peg the CPU to 100% just so it can check a flag that will eventually be set in some other thread is far from the ideal choice.

I suggesting using `group.wait`. Here's a rough outline of the code:

```
for siteIndex in 0..<countySites.count {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    distanceAndDirections.calculate { (response, error) in
        // stuff
        group.leave()
    })
    group.wait()
}
```

Note the change to create a new group inside the loop and to eliminate the `while` busy loop.

Another option over using a group is to use a semaphore.

The most critical thing here is to ensure that nothing done inside the async block results in any attempt to run code on the same queue as the main `for` loop.

And of course you must make sure this main `for` loop is not being run on the main queue.

Comment: No, when I say queue, I mean queue. A queue may consist of one or more threads but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: I've read about the main thread of execution so should that be main THREADS of execution where there is only one main queue with one or many threads of execution?

Comment: so the main queue is composed of multiple code blocks or functions for execution on a single thread?

Comment: can you recommend a good reading resource to learn the fundamentals of multi-threading, concurrency, tasks and queues?

Comment: I have tried the code fragment you suggested above but the app just stops running and appears stuck as if it is waiting for something to happen that never does.

Comment: What debugging have you done? What's actually happening? Have you verified that the `calculate` completion block is being called? Have you ensured that `leave` is always called from that completion block? Where exactly is the code blocking?

Comment: The closure is not being called but the code is executing up to the point just before the ```calculate()``` method is called. By the way, there is an error in your code fragment, you have an extra parenthesis to the right of the closure's closing brace.

Comment: ```group.leave()``` is called in the closure.

Comment: The code is blocking in the asynchronous function call ```calculate()```

Comment: Any solution please, even i got same error directions not available